# TypeScript complains about conditionally assigning class: JSX element type 'TouchableComponent' does not have any construct or call signatures

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, jsx

I have this piece of code:

```
protected getCardContent = (message: string): JSX.Element => {
    const { placeInfo } = this.props;
    const TouchableComponent = Platform.OS === 'ios' ? TouchableOpacity : TouchableNativeFeedback
    return (
        <View>
            <Text>{placeInfo.name}'s phone number:</Text>
            <TouchableComponent onPress={() => {}}>
                <Text>{placeInfo.phoneNumber}</Text>
            </TouchableComponent>
        </View>
    )
}
```

When calling `this.getCardContent` in my render method it works on both iOS and Android devices; however, TS complains saying:

```
const TouchableComponent: typeof TouchableOpacity | typeof TouchableNativeFeedback
JSX element type 'TouchableComponent' does not have any construct or call signatures.
```

Is it because `TouchableComponent` can be of either constructor type, thus TS doesn't explicitly know what the instantiated type is? What would be a better way to solve this issue that works with the TS compiler?

Comment: could you try this ?: const TouchableComponent = (Platform.OS === 'ios' ? TouchableOpacity : TouchableNativeFeedback) as React.ElementType

Comment: @tpliakas casting it like that does remove the error, interesting. Do you want to post this as an answer to get credit?

Comment: @tpliakas, using [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) basically means (partially) opting out of TypeScript's type checking. I would not recommend this unless it's the only option (or you simply want to save time and not bother by going for `as any`). To illustrate the difference: My answer would throw an error if you change `TouchableOpacity` or `TouchableNativeFeedback` to something else (of a completely different type). Your approach wouldn't.

Answer (score 4):

TypeScript does not infer the desired type for `TouchableComponent`. Without running the following code myself, I got rid of all TypeScript errors like this:

```
import { ComponentType } from 'react';
import { Platform, TouchableOpacity, TouchableOpacityProps, TouchableNativeFeedback, TouchableNativeFeedbackProps, View, Text } from 'react-native';

const getCardContent = (message: string): JSX.Element => {
    const { placeInfo } = this.props;
    const TouchableComponent: ComponentType<TouchableOpacityProps | TouchableNativeFeedbackProps> = Platform.OS === 'ios' ? TouchableOpacity : TouchableNativeFeedback;
    return (
        <View>
            <Text>{placeInfo.name}'s phone number:</Text>
            <TouchableComponent onPress={() => {}}>
                <Text>{placeInfo.phoneNumber}</Text>
            </TouchableComponent>
        </View>
    );
}
```

The only thing I changed is the declaration of `TouchableComponent`: `const TouchableComponent: ComponentType<TouchableOpacityProps & TouchableNativeFeedbackProps>`.

Why these types?

- [`TouchableOpacity`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/b8f4f8a0c8d6d94e983c49718afd3ed1b32d1a81/types/react-native/index.d.ts#L5000) indirectly extends [`React.Component<TouchableOpacityProps>`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/b8f4f8a0c8d6d94e983c49718afd3ed1b32d1a81/types/react-native/index.d.ts#L4995)
- [`TouchableNativeFeedback`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/b8f4f8a0c8d6d94e983c49718afd3ed1b32d1a81/types/react-native/index.d.ts#L5058) indirectly extends [`React.Component<TouchableNativeFeedbackProps>`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/b8f4f8a0c8d6d94e983c49718afd3ed1b32d1a81/types/react-native/index.d.ts#L5056)

Comment: This seems like an interesting approach, it does seem to have some potential issues though. Would you need to include `style` and any other props that `TouchableComponent` could possibly need to the generic parameter?

Comment: @ehutchllew, yes, sorry for that. I was too lazy to analyze the types more accurately yesterday. I've updated my answer with more appropriate types now. For example, `style` is now also covered. If you check the type declarations I linked to, it's a bit of a mess, though. If other properties that you need are still missing, you would have to revise the used types once more. If this solves your problem, then please accept my answer. Thank you!